Including QT libraries in gstreamer for android
I am trying to compile gstreamer library so it can be included with my QT app on Android.
I want to use gstreamer qt plugins in my app so I compiled gstreamer sdk using cerbero with qt plugins supported. I can succesfully compile my app with that sdk but I have linker issues when compiling gstreamer into final apk.
Here is my Android.mk file:
ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/armv7
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm64
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86_64
else
$(error Target arch ABI not supported: $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_QT5)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0 gobject-2.0
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_LIBS      := -liconv
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk

When i try to compile i get a lot of linker errors ( i cropped the output because it was wayy to long)
make[1]: Entering directory '/myproject/app/libgstreamer_android'
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16.    
make[1]: Leaving directory '/myproject/app/libgstreamer_android'
make[1]: Entering directory '/myproject/app/libgstreamer_android'
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-android-build/armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-android-build/armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-android-build/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so
/home/tcikel/Downloads/cerbero/build/sources/android_universal/armv7/gstreamer-1.0/subprojects/gst-plugins-good/_builddir/../ext/qt/gstqtoverlay.cc:301: error: undefined reference to 'QArrayData::shared_null'
/home/tcikel/Downloads/cerbero/build/sources/android_universal/armv7/gstreamer-1.0/subprojects/gst-plugins-good/_builddir/../ext/qt/gstqtoverlay.cc:489: error: undefined reference to 'QCoreApplication::self'

If I remove the "$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_QT5)" the build does finish succesfully.
I have all the needed QT libraries on the system where I am building, but I cant find a way to tell the linker succesfully where to look for the qt libraries. I have read the enter link description here docs and trie to include libraries using
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/path/to/qt/libraries -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5QmlModels -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core

but was not successful.
Any idea how to solve this?
